# mvn version is failing while setting the new version

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

When i am trying to update internal version using `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion` i am getting below error.

In my automation CI/CD script i am trying to upgrade maven internal version.
I am new to this, How can i fix this issue ?

`Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.3:set (default-cli) on project top: Project version is inherited from parent. -> [Help 1]`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>2023.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>****/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>top</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name> Suite</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>

        <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>ab_initio</module>
        <module>ab_initio/module</module>
        <module>autoactions</module>
        <module>cluster-access</module>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>config</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>parse-version</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>parse-version</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/other</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>build.******.env.sh</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is my parent pom file similarly i have multiple child pom's.I tried multiple ways to update but still seeing the same error.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you can't set a version if the project has a parent.

Comment: Please show all pom files and the structure ...furthermore you are using version old plugin versions (versions-maven-plugin currently 2.16.0) etc.